# jquery UI Tabs - run script on slide change

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I have searched and read multiple forums, but I can't seem to solve this.

SET-UP: I have a simple jquery audio player set up in one of the tabs. When someone clicks a song title, it plays that audio in a div called #gs-audio. If they click on another song title, it changes the track or, if they re-click the same one, it pauses the audio.

PROBLEM: if someone clicks to another tab, the audio continues to play

WHAT I'VE TRIED:

```
$(".tabs-outter-wrapper").tabs({
    show: { effect: "slide", duration: 800, direction: "right" },
    hide: { effect: "slide", duration: 800, direction: "left" },
    show: function(event, ui) {
            var audioElement = document.getElementById("gs-audio"),
                current = audioElement.getAttribute("src");
    
        if (typeof current !== typeof undefined && current !== false) {
            audioElement.pause();
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried changing that second `show` to `activate` but neither seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea, in that you need to run some logic to update the state of the audio element when the tabs change, however you're not using the right property for it.

`show` is used to set up how the animation used when tabs change. You need to use `activate` or `beforeActivate` instead:

```js
var audioElement = document.getElementById("gs-audio");

$(".tabs-outter-wrapper").tabs({
  show: {
    effect: "slide",
    duration: 800,
    direction: "right"
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "slide",
    duration: 800,
    direction: "left"
  },
  activate: function(e, ui) {
    audioElement.pause();
  }
});
```

Note that there's no need for the `if` condition to check the current URL of the `audio` to see if it was already playing, just `pause()` it regardless.